# Rashi and the death of Tzadikim

Tags: death, rashi, tzaddikim, mabul

In Parshat Chaye Sarah, Rashi states in Bereshit 25:17 (from Chabad.org) 
ויגוע: לא נאמרה גויעה אלא בצדיקים
Translated as : and he expired: Heb. וַיִגְוַע. [The term] גְוִיעָה is mentioned only regarding the righteous. — [B.B. 16b]

After a search in Tanach, it seems that ויגוע is found for Ishmael, for Avraham Avinou, for Itshak avinou, for Yaakov avinou and surprisingly for the generation of the Mabul (Bereshit 7:21):
 "ויגוע כל בשר הרמש על הארץ בעוף ובבהמה ובחיה ובכל השרץ השרץ על הארץ וכל האדם"

Does it mean that the people who perished in the Mabul were also Tzaddikim?

Comment: Yishmael was a tzaddik. (Rashi on Bereishis 25:9.) But that doesn't explain the generation of the Mabul.

Comment: A big shkoyach to you on being מכוון to רבינא!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ravina himself asks this question to R. Hama Bar Buzi who suggested this, as recorded in [Bava Batra (16b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Rav Hama bar Buzi answered that we only say this when the term gevia and asifa are both used. In the case of the flood, the term asifa is not used.